# Get sales Orders between dates

Tags: vb.net, magento, soap-client

How can I make a call to the Magento SOAP API v2 to get all of the sales orders between a set of dates in vb.net?

Here is what I have tried so far, but it returns `0` sales orders despite the fact that they are present.

```
Dim ae As associativeEntity = New associativeEntity()
ae.key = "status"
ae.value = "processing"
Dim params As filters = New filters

Dim dateFilter As complexFilter
dateFilter = New complexFilter()
dateFilter.key = "created_at"
Dim nestedFilterFrom As associativeMultiEntity = New associativeMultiEntity()
nestedFilterFrom.key = "gteq"
nestedFilterFrom.value = New String() {DateTime.Parse(fromDate).ToUniversalTime.ToString()}
dateFilter.value = nestedFilterFrom
Dim dateToFilter As complexFilter = New complexFilter()
Dim nestedFilterTo As associativeMultiEntity = New associativeMultiEntity()
nestedFilterTo.key = "lteq"
nestedFilterTo.value = New String() {DateTime.Parse(toDate).ToUniversalTime.ToString()}
dateToFilter.key = "created_at"
dateToFilter.value = nestedFilterTo

params.complex_filter = New complexFilter() {dateFilter, dateToFilter}    
magentoWS.salesOrderList(sessionID, params)
```

I have been able to get the same code to work matching on status, like below.

```
Dim ae As associativeEntity = New associativeEntity
Dim params As filters = New filters()
ae.key = "status"
ae.value = "processing"
params.filter = New associativeEntity() {ae}
magentoWS.salesOrderList(sessionID, params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format must be the following for the filters to work.

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

I only discovered this, because that is how it was in Magento's [SOAP "v2" XML Request example](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html). It would have been nice to specify this in the documentation or in their response, but *se la vie*. In case anyone is interested, here is the code.

```
Dim ae As associativeEntity = New associativeEntity With { .key = "status", .value = "processing" }
Dim params As filters = New filters

Const createdAt As String = "created_at"
Const magentoDateTimeFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"

Dim nestedFilterFrom As associativeMultiEntity =
    New associativeMultiEntity With {.key = "from", .value = New String() {fromDate.ToString(magentoDateTimeFormat)}}
Dim dateFromFilter As complexFilter = New complexFilter With {.key = createdAt, .value = nestedFilterFrom}

Dim nestedFilterTo As associativeMultiEntity =
    New associativeMultiEntity With {.key = "to", .value = New String() {toDate.ToString(magentoDateTimeFormat)}}
Dim dateToFilter As complexFilter = New complexFilter With {.key = createdAt, .value = nestedFilterFrom}

params.complex_filter = New complexFilter() {dateFromFilter, dateToFilter}    
magentoWS.salesOrderList(sessionID, params)
```

It should be noted that in this case, the `from` and `to` filters are equivalent to the `lteq` and `gteq`. I found `from` and `to` to make more sense in this context but results are the same.

Comment: `Dim dateFromFilter As complexFilter = New complexFilter With {.key = createdAt, .value = nestedFilterFrom}` You can't do that: nestedFilterFrom is a associativeMultiEntity and cannot be converted to an associativeEntity

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function getMageOrdersListByFilter(ByVal fromDate As DateTime, ByVal toDate As DateTime) As MagentoService.salesOrderListEntity()
    GetMageSessionId()

    Dim f As MagentoService.filters = New MagentoService.filters

    Const createdAt As String = "created_at"
    Dim magentoDateTimeFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    magentoDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    Dim cpf(2) As MagentoService.complexFilter
    cpf(0) = New MagentoService.complexFilter With {.key = createdAt, .value = New MagentoService.associativeEntity With {.key = "from", .value = New String(fromDate.ToString(magentoDateTimeFormat))}}
    'HACK FIX: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=8073
    cpf(1) = New MagentoService.complexFilter With {.key = "/*fake*/created_at", .value = New MagentoService.associativeEntity With {.key = "to", .value = New String(toDate.ToString(magentoDateTimeFormat))}}

    f.complex_filter = cpf

    Dim oList() As MagentoService.salesOrderListEntity = Nothing

    Try
        oList = mage.salesOrderList(sessionId, f)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return oList

End Function
```

Comment: Why would you swallow the exception when you call `mage.salesOrderList(sessionId, f)`?

Comment: Testing purpose, just in case my connection is down.